# When I render the objects are in a different position then they are in camera perspective

Tags: rendering, camera

I am guessing this is a very simple fix and apologise for my ignorance in advance.\
[image]

Comment: The Scene's camera will render every time, not the selected. To adjust the Scene's camera go to the Scene properties panel. A little cone, a sphere and a dot its icon in the right side.

Comment: Hi FFeller, Thanks for the response. When I go to the scene properties panel what is the next step. Under scene and then camera I have selected the camera which is set up to create the view above but it is rendering the same image as before. What setting do I need to change?

Comment: It looks the camera position is the same on the two pictures, but you zoomed in with the mouse scrool in the 3d view. It doesn't count for the camera so zoom out, till you can see the camera's borders, then move the camera forward to make a closer picture.